# Is it possible to find the similarity in images by only based on available colour intensity in the images ?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing, computer-vision

Is it possible to find the similarity in images by only based on available colour intensity in the images ? What are the challenges regarding this problem ? Is there any way to find a solution for this  [image]

I have images like below with 7 sections and all the images have different colour intensity in those sections. How find the similarity ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many similarity metrics available. One well known similarity index measure is Jaccard index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). The range of similarity values is [0,1]. 0 being completely dissimilar and 1 being identical. 
There are other similarity measures that can be used. 
In the current scenario, each pixel will have RGB values. How is it that you are going to identify similarity between two values of R between a pair of pixels will lead you to the answer of finding the similarity. One way to find it is just calculating min/max principle (Please refer to the generalized jaccard similarity and distance section in the above mentioned page).